# Loading xslx file from server to React

Tags: reactjs, xlsx, rtk-query

Dear fellow developers!

Tell me how to transfer a file with the .xlsx extension from the Spring backend to the React frontend?
Let's get my code first. This is my backend controller which returns a ByteArrayResource:

```
@PostMapping("/download-report")
public ResponseEntity<ByteArrayResource> generateReport(@RequestBody ReportAttributesWithFiltersDto attributesWithFilters) {
    var resource = reportBuilder.generateReport(attributesWithFilters);
    var headers = getReportHeaders();

    return new ResponseEntity<>(resource, headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}

private HttpHeaders getReportHeaders() {
    var contentDisposition = ContentDisposition.builder("attachment")
        .filename("attachment; filename=my_file.xlsx")
        .build();
    var headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(new MediaType("application", "force-download"));
    headers.setContentDisposition(contentDisposition);
    return headers;
}
```

The backend performs well, if you test it in the development environment, it will return the file in response.
The file downloads fine and there are no problems. **Backend shouldn't be a problem.**

The problems start when I upload the file on the frontend.
Here is my request:

```
downloadReport: builder.mutation({
      query: (body) => ({
        url: paths.downloadReport,
        method: "POST",
        body: body,
        responseHandler: "blob",
      }),
    }),
```

What nonsense I get in response, this is some kind of nightmare!
In the case of using a blob, I get this:

```
res:
   data:
       undefined
```

If I set *responseHandler: "text"*, then I get this:

```
{
    "data": "PK\u0003\u0004\u0014\u0000\b\b\b\u0000�,U\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0013\u0000\u0000\u0000[Content_Types].xml�S�n�0\u0010����*6�PU\u0015�C\u001f�\u0016��\u0003\\{�X�%����]\u00078�R�\nq�cfgfW�d�q�ZCB\u0013|��|�*�*h㻆},^�{Va�^K\u001b<4�\u00076�N\u0016�\bXQ�ǆ�9�\u0007!P��$�\u0010�\u0013҆�d�c�D�j);\u0010��ѝP�g��E�M'O�ʕ����H7L�h���R���G��^�'�\u0003\u0007{\u0013�\b�zސʮ\u001bB��3\u001c�\u000b˙��h.�h�W�жF�\u000ej娄CQՠ똈���}ιL�U:\u0012\u0014D�\u0013����%އ����,�B���[�\t��\u001e ;˱�\t�{N��~��X�p�\u001cykOL�\u0004\u0018�kN�V��ܿBZ~����q\u0018��\u000f �a\u0019\u001fr��{O�\u0001PK\u0007\bz��q;\u0001\u0000\u0000\u001c\u0004\u0000\u0000PK\u0003\u0004\u0014\u0000\b\b\b\u0000�,U\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u000b\u0000\u0000\u0000_rels/.rels���j�0\f�_���8�`�Q��2�m��\u00014[ILb��ږ���.[K\n\u001b�($}�\u0007�v?�I�Q.���uӂ�h���\u001bx>=��@\u0015��p�H\u0006\"�~�}�\t�n����*\"\u0016\u0003�H�׺؁\u0002��\u0013���8\u0007�Z�^'�#��7m{��O\u0006�3��\u0019�G�\u0006u�ܓ\u0018�'��y|a\u001e�����D�\t��\u000el_\u0003EYȾ�\u0000���vql\u001f3�ML�eh\u0016���*�\u0004��\\3�Y0���oJ׏�\u0003\t:\u0014��^\b�\u001f�}\u0002PK\u0007\b��z��\u0000\u0000\u0000I\u0002\u0000\u0000PK\u0003\u0004\u0014\u0000\b\b\b\u0000�,U\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0010\u0000\u0000\u0000docProps/app.xmlM��\n�0\u0010D��\u0010ro�z\u0010�4� �'{�\u000f\b��\u0006�MHV�盓z�\u0019��T��E�1e\u0017�����\u0002Ɇ�ѳ����:�No7jH!bb�Y�\u0007�V���\u0004�����T�)$o���0M��9ؗGb�7�\u0001pe�\u0011�*~�R�>��Y�EB��\u0014�\u0018nW\u0005������\u0000PK\u0007\b6n�!�\u0000\u0000\u0000�\u0000\u0000\u0000PK\u0003\u0004\u0014\u0000\b\b\b\u0000�,U\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0011\u0000\u0000\u0000docProps/core.xmlm��J�0\u0010F_�依�EqC�E�\u0005Aq���w!\u0019�b�C\u0012����u���%��\u001c&_�=�1yG�\u0007�kB��$�����j����\u000b������X\u0013mȶ��e�8�;cх\u0001}\u00125�3ak҇`\u0019�\u0017=*�H�\u0018�\u0018�x�Wׁ��w\bE�����%\u000f\u001cfajW#9)�X��͍�@\n�\u0011\u0015���f\u0014~؀N�\u0007�d%�~X�i���\\��\u0011����ò|:���\u0002IS��L8�\u0001e\u0012\u0005,|���w�T^]�;�\u0014yQ��&�EK7����=W�k~\u0016~��k.c!=&����[�+�Ss�\tPK\u0007\bȂ`�\u0005\u0001\u0000\u0000�\u0001\u0000\u0000PK\u0003\u0004\u0014\u0000\b\b\b\u0000�,U\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0014\u0000\u0000\u0000xl/sharedStrings.xml���J�@\u0014����0d�Bҙ&��!M�\u001b��ӕ�(5�\u0001��L�.�\".*\u0016ԅ��}�x)F{�\u0015μ�'��4\u0005e`����?�93F��9 G��m�-J�\u0014���V�=ۭ\u0016���5Y�J����y@*^�\rP��Hõ\u000f\u001b��$��\bڸ�(Ղ��S�+5�)�W�\\��{�S\u000e�ӯR^���\u001e�YV�\u001cP��\u001cuʶ+�\u0006�M#0�+�a�+$Ї\b\u000f�8�Р�i�X2��@\b}q=3w\u0007a\u001c'�\u0014F�\u000eo(\u001d�M{Z��B0\u001d�6��'D\t�{\u0018�6\u0011\u0017��G�\b]^g���;Z��@���\b��&�H�@�J\u000f�3q���gl�j:�0E�YAN+[鬮j��R�VP��E����6|\u001c1��x�;ޝ�}scI��Y��-�D\u0013YZ�A\u0010{<\"q..\u0012‡x�\u0005x\u0014MD|\u0013��?\bU=SHi�\\.���P�d\u0013���\u000f�'.q\u000f�7���������,N�\u0019�5��_�\u0014\u001f��\rPK\u0007\b��-��\u0001\u0000\u0000�\u0002\u0000\u0000PK\u0003\u0004\u0014\u0000\b\b\b\u0000�,U\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\r\u0000\u0000\u0000xl/styles.xml���n� \u0010��J}\u0007���d���&C%W��J]�9ۨpX@\"�O_0N�L\u001d:����\u001f���n4���ye���UA\t`c�®�\u001f��iKw���aҰ�\u0001\u0002�\u000e�\u0015�C\u0018^\u0018�M\u000fF��\u001d\u0000�Ik�\u0011!��c~p �O&�٦(��\u0011\n)/�dj\u0013<i�\tCE\u000b�x�Z�*k�\u0005^�or\u0016:*i���Xm\u001dQ(a\u0004Y�m�P\u0018�]�B��S3O\u0018��,o�0O��\u0019��%��[��Ii�;Ćf���\b\u0001\u001cֱ K~�\u0006�(Z�������}�91�8�\u0010/>Z'�\u0016nߟ%^jhC48��)\u0006;�t\u0018�51�Jt\u0016�NȋcI\"�\u0001��iu��\u001d{lI���L����_�8ВfL.\u0012�����ƒ����hv���\u000fPK\u0007\b����E\u0001\u0000\u0000�\u0002\u0000\u0000PK\u0003\u0004\u0014\u0000\b\b\b\u0000�,U\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u000f\u0000\u0000\u0000xl/workbook.xml���N�0\u0010�w$�����\u0001� ��\u0005!uc(�}i��v�3-s\u0017ނ��=�7�I\u0015`d:��������\u001e#��%\u0014\u000b\u0001\f�\u000e��������=,�ˋ�\u0010�n\u0013Žeޓ�6���t�N�\"���\tѩ�c�r�#*C-br\u001d�\u0016�;e=�\re��#4���\u0018��C�Β��J�-��'��=GfT��A�JhTG\b���ͫ�\u0003��cdJ'�ǵ�H\u0010#���S�y2�\u001cJ8}\u000e����5\u001c���\u001a\tqen�M�*�b�̧|~V\u0003PK\u0007\b\u0007$�h�\u0000\u0000\u0000b\u0001\u0000\u0000PK\u0003\u0004\u0014\u0000\b\b\b\u0000�,U\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u001a\u0000\u0000\u0000xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels��Mk�0\f@���}q��\u0018�n/c����\u0000c+qh\"\u0019K�迟���@\u0007;�$��{\u000f��~Γy�\"#���i� \u0005�#\r\u000e^�O7�`D=E?1�\u0003b�n��8y�?$�YLE�8H���Z\t\tg/\rg����^�\f6�p�\u0003�U���r΀%�좃��\u001d��/\u0003�\u0003I�`|�Rˤ��:f����~\f���mF�\u000bv����\u001c�:���ׯ�������p9HB�Sy\u001dݵK~\u0004�\u0018����\u000bPK\u0007\b�\u0003;��\u0000\u0000\u00003\u0002\u0000\u0000PK\u0003\u0004\u0014\u0000\b\b\b\u0000�,U\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0018\u0000\u0000\u0000xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml��[�� \u0018���?\u0010�+��э��vִ\u0017M6=^3����\u0001fܟ_p\fE�l:���<|/�|���e���rѱ1���B@ǒU��d����]\f��oҙ�g�R*�*\u0018E\u0006[)�;�D�ҁ\b�MtT�f| RMy���)����G�u#4�n�yZu\u0003\u001d����:�\u000f�]�C����\u001f\u001d��5\u0006z�\u0013c�z�ʠR�������T�%?S]��(/\u0016�'\u000e*Z�s/���#�V�/\rէ����b�\u0005C�\u000f\u0000���,�sW�V�\u0002'�q�F8��<\u000bɆ�W��\u000bNTȢ��5L\u0016^���:8����?�\u001a�Q��\n\u0012'v�(�9*X�\u0002\u0013�8��q\nנ�>�$H�w�T�fE&\u000b�ο\u001f9�vq���H���̀�6�M��A5T\u0015\b5��n�.�he�m�m�\u0007��-;��߲G�\u0005[V�,4\f)g#��8^\u0016�W9��ݱ�\u0015��mvع�,޹�,ٹ��s�.�\u001by�uy�\u0015y�y��\u001c7pז�\r�����`珬\u001b4��~&��F\u0001NL�;�^\u001eG��1I����V=qf��Z.� ��gf\u0019K6������4�\u0005PK\u0007\b�Q�.�\u0001\u0000\u0000}\u0005\u0000\u0000PK\u0001\u0002\u0014\u0000\u0014\u0000\b\b\b\u0000�,Uz��q;\u0001\u0000\u0000\u001c\u0004\u0000\u0000\u0013\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000[Content_Types].xmlPK\u0001\u0002\u0014\u0000\u0014\u0000\b\b\b\u0000�,U��z��\u0000\u0000\u0000I\u0002\u0000\u0000\u000b\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000|\u0001\u0000\u0000_rels/.relsPK\u0001\u0002\u0014\u0000\u0014\u0000\b\b\b\u0000�,U6n�!�\u0000\u0000\u0000�\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0010\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000�\u0002\u0000\u0000docProps/app.xmlPK\u0001\u0002\u0014\u0000\u0014\u0000\b\b\b\u0000�,UȂ`�\u0005\u0001\u0000\u0000�\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0011\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000i\u0003\u0000\u0000docProps/core.xmlPK\u0001\u0002\u0014\u0000\u0014\u0000\b\b\b\u0000�,U��-��\u0001\u0000\u0000�\u0002\u0000\u0000\u0014\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000�\u0004\u0000\u0000xl/sharedStrings.xmlPK\u0001\u0002\u0014\u0000\u0014\u0000\b\b\b\u0000�,U����E\u0001\u0000\u0000�\u0002\u0000\u0000\r\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000�\u0006\u0000\u0000xl/styles.xmlPK\u0001\u0002\u0014\u0000\u0014\u0000\b\b\b\u0000�,U\u0007$�h�\u0000\u0000\u0000b\u0001\u0000\u0000\u000f\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0010\b\u0000\u0000xl/workbook.xmlPK\u0001\u0002\u0014\u0000\u0014\u0000\b\b\b\u0000�,U�\u0003;��\u0000\u0000\u00003\u0002\u0000\u0000\u001a\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u00006\t\u0000\u0000xl/_rels/workbook.xml.relsPK\u0001\u0002\u0014\u0000\u0014\u0000\b\b\b\u0000�,U�Q�.�\u0001\u0000\u0000}\u0005\u0000\u0000\u0018\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000R\n\u0000\u0000xl/worksheets/sheet1.xmlPK\u0005\u0006\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\t\u0000\t\u0000?\u0002\u0000\u0000�\f\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000"
}
```

What can I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

ok guys,
I found the answer to my question. The thing is, I was using Redux for the request. For some reason it didn't load my file.
Now I switched to fetch request and everything started working

```
    const requestReport = (selectedObj) => fetch(`/api/reports/download-report`, {
        headers: new Headers({'content-type': 'application/json'}),
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(selectedObj),
    }).
```